# do not have the authority to access the file created by mkfifo

Tags: process, pipe, file-permissions, fifo, mkfifo

While using the FIFO to transmit information between different processes, I found out that the file that the mkfifo create cannot be accessed by the processes. I do not know how to change my program. Please help :(

```
    if (mkfifo("signal", O_CREAT) < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Errors occur :(" << endl;
        cerr << errno << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
```

And the authority of the file named signal is like the following:

```
    p---rwx---
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the manpage, you would have known that `O_CREAT` is an invalid argument to `mkfifo()`:

> mkfifo() makes a FIFO special file with name pathname.  mode specifies the FIFO's permissions.  It is modified by the process's umask in the usual way: the permissions of the created file are (mode & ~umask).

The permission bit flags are defined in `<sys/stat.h>` and can be consulted in your system by reading the manpage for `stat(2)`. Here's the relevant list:

```
S_IRUSR    00400     owner has read permission
S_IWUSR    00200     owner has write permission
S_IXUSR    00100     owner has execute permission

S_IRGRP    00040     group has read permission
S_IWGRP    00020     group has write permission
S_IXGRP    00010     group has execute permission

S_IROTH    00004     others have read permission
S_IWOTH    00002     others have write permission
S_IXOTH    00001     others have execute permission
```

So, your problem is solved by passing the right permission flags to `mkfifo()`. Say you want `rw-rw-rw`, then you'd do this:

```
mkfifo("signal", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH);
```